# VBA Match function to find ActiveCell Value on inactive sheet and change value on active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I try to find the value of the Active cell where my cursor is using the application.match function on a different sheet. If it is found i want to change the value of a cell on my active sheet based on the ActiveCell.Row and a determined column.

I tried to use this code

```
Sub test()
    Dim wert As String
    Dim such1 As String
    Dim var As Integer

    such1 = ActiveCell.Value
    On Error Resume Next
    var = Application.Match(such1, Worksheets(Test1).Columns(1), 0)

    If Err = 0 Then
        wert = Sheets("Test2").Cell(var, "N").Value
        Sheets("Test2").Cell(ActiveCell.Row, "O").Value = wert
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not existent"
    End If

End Sub
```

Somehow i always get the error message. I dont understand why though. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You haven't declared nor assigned any value to variable `InactiveSheet`, so macro cannot found such worksheet. Another question: do you have a worksheet called `ActiveSheet`? If you want to use the worksheet that is currently active you need to use just `ActiveSheet.Cell` instead of `Sheets("ActiveSheet").Cell`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. With InactiveSheet and Active sheet i just wanted to be generic. So InactiveSheet would be for example Test 1, ActiveSheet would be Test 2 . I changed it above.I am right in reading the microsoft instruction on how to write the sheet name for the application.match function i hope. Other than i was used to i have to just write it without the " " .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use syntax like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim foundRow As Variant
    Dim activeRow As Long
    Dim foundN As String

    activeRow = ActiveCell.Row

    foundRow = Application.Match(ActiveCell, Worksheets("Test1").Columns(1), 0)

    If Not IsError(foundRow) Then
        foundN = Worksheets("Test2").Cells(foundRow, "N").Value
        Worksheets("Test2").Cells(activeRow, "O").Value = foundN
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not existent"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Mistakes in your code:

- `Worksheets(test1)` should be `Worksheets("Test1")`
- `Worksheets("Test2").Cell` should be `Worksheets("Test2").Cells` ("s" at the end of Cells)
- There are subtle differences between **`Application.Match()`** and **`WorksheetFunction.Match()`**

  - `WorksheetFunction.Match()` is not as reliable as `Application.Match()`
  - `WorksheetFunction.Match()` **throws** a run-time error

    - you need to use the statement `On Error Resume Next` to bypass the VBA error
  - `Application.Match()` **returns an Error Object**

    - the statement `On Error Resume Next` doesn't work
    - to check the return value you have to use `If IsError(Application.Match(...))`
    - Note how *foundRow* is defined: `Dim foundRow As`**`Variant`**
    - The return value can be the row number (a Long) or an Error object (Variant)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, great! And also thank you a lot for your helpful explanation!